# For loop with setInterval

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have written a `for` loop using `setInterval`. The intention was to "drip feed" the output of the for loop to the user. So basically I would like to send the `console.log` message every `10000ms` and output it on the console of the user.

See my example below:

```
function longForLoop(limit) {
    for (var i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        setInterval(() => {
            console.log("This is a long for loop. We are at " + i)
        }, 10000)
    }
}

longForLoop(10)
```

However, I only get the full result back as a whole?

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong here?

Appreciate your replies!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve?  `setInterval()` is non-blocking so your `for` loop immediately runs to completion and meanwhile you've started `limit` timers that will repeat forever.  I don't see how this does anything useful and you haven't describe what you're really trying to do.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thank you for your reply. Please see my updated question.

Comment: So you just want `setInterval(() => { console.log("This is a long for loop. We are at " + i++); }, 10000)` with no `for` loop?

Comment: @melpomene I would like to print this message x times.

Comment: Then I guess you get to learn how `setInterval` works.

Comment: Curious: why are you using `setInterval`, which schedules a never ending stream of calls (unless you explicitly clear it), rather than `setTimeout`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `setInterval` with for loop in these cases as the `setInterval` will run without condition. use either one of these.I used `setInterval` without loop and I am using `clearInterval` once the condition reaches

```js
function longForLoop(limit) {
  var i = 0;
  var ref = setInterval(() => {
    console.log("This is a long for loop. We are at " + ++i);
    if (i == limit) clearInterval(ref);
  }, 1000);
}

longForLoop(10);
```

In other ways you could also use `setTimeout` with recursive function

Answer (score 0):

You can use [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) instead of [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp). Look at my example:

```
function longForLoop(limit) {
for (var i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    (function(j) {
       setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('j',j);      
       }, 100 + (1000 * j));
  })(i);
 }
}

longForLoop(10)
```

Answer (score -1):

The variable i is  bound to the value outside your anonymous function. Use code below which passes value of i to function

```
function longForLoop(limit) {
    for (var i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        function innerFunction(valOfi)
        {
                console.log("This is a long for loop. We are at " + valOfi);
        }
        setInterval(innerFunction(i) , 10000)
    }
}

longForLoop(10)
```